# How to display images in React that are grabbed from an Express server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm just a little confused on how to serve the assets correctly from the source folder.

Relevant server-side code (The client makes a request to /images, the server sends back the file names):

```
const images = './static/images/';
app.use(express.static('static/images'))

app.get('/images', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    fs.readdir(images, (err, files) => {
        res.send(files);
      });
});
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
public
   index.html
server (houses Node/Express code)
   index.js
src (houses React code)
   App.js
static
   images
      image1, image2, image4, image4
```

If I try to display the image in React (state.currImage being one of the 4 file names):

```
<img alt="scan" src={ require(this.state.currImage)}
```

I get an error saying "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module './static/images/file1.jpg'"

Comment: Can you ```console.log('[image]', this.state.currImage)``` and let me know what it says?  Also... can you post your whole component so we can see how this.state.currImage get set?

Comment: why are you attempting to call `require` in the browser? why are you giving an array of filesystem paths to `res.send` instead of urls?

Comment: @Dan O The images are stored on my computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you could maybe remove the `require` from the image loading considering it's a path to an image and not a path to a javascript module.

```
<img alt="scan" src={this.state.currImage}
```

You may need to update the url of those images to point to the server url. Right now the string is `./static/images/file1.jpg` but it may need to be `/images/file1.jpg`.